# Writing to specific column from csv file

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible in Python to copy data from a separate csv and place it in a specific column of another csv?

I'd like to take only the first column of each csv file `file1.csv` `file2.csv` `file3.csv`

```
File1.csv Column A
File2.csv Column A
File3.csv Column A
```

and have a single `output.csv` with the `column A` data of all those csv's being written to its own column

```
output.csv Column A (file1)
output.csv Column B (file2)
output.csv Column C (file3)
```

Here is what I have for the filtering portion, not sure how to do it for`writer`

```
 csvinputlist = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']


for csvinput in csvinputlist
    reader = csv.reader(open(r'{0}'.format(csvinput)), delimiter=',') 
    filtered = filter(lambda p:column A == p[0], reader)
    csv.writer(open(output.csv ???????
```

Comment: What is the point of `csvinput = csvinputlist`?

Comment: @IshanM I'm not sure why I put that, i'll remove. Can something like `csv.writer(open(output.csv, 'a' newline='',), delimiter=',').writecolumns(filtered)` be done? instead of `writerows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd
csvinputlist = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']
csvinput = csvinputlist
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, csvinput in enumerate(csvinputlist):
    reader = pd.read_csv(csvinput) 
    df['A{}'.format(i+1)]=reader['A']

df.to_csv('constructed.csv')
```

Where 'A' represents your column header of the column you want to read. If your column do not have headers you can assign them as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
csvinputlist = ['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']
csvinput = csvinputlist
headers=['A', 'B', 'C'] # continue for as many column that are in the file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, csvinput in enumerate(csvinputlist):
    reader = pd.read_csv(csvinput, header=None, names=headers) 
    df['A{}'.format(i+1)]=reader['A']

df.to_csv('constructed.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the `'A'` represent? its giving me `KeyError: 'A'` when I run it. The first column has a bunch of different numbers, I just put A to shorten it

Comment: @iOSecure please see the updated answer, hope this solves the `Keyerror`.

Comment: It did, thanks so much! this is exactly what I was trying to do. Just needed to capitalize the f in `Dataframe` for it to work.

Comment: Glad to help. Thank you for pointing out the mistake, I will fix it in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to filter out a single specific column inside your script if there are multiple columns? I can't figure out how to do it without filtering the actual input files down to one column.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do? Do you want to delete a column from the csv that you are reading?

Comment: When I run the script it copies multiple columns from the input.csv's in to its own column. (in my example I only used one my fault) I was just wondering if its possible for it to ignore all those columns and read only a single one so it only outputs one to `constructed.csv`.

Comment: Yes you can, add the `usecols` argument to the `pd.read_csv` function.
You can then give a list as a variable to `usecols`. The list containing the names of columns you want to use.